# Mapping field columns with D8 migrate and d7_node source plugin

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to write a D8 migrations files but the following one isn't working on the source 'body/value' because it resolves to a null value instead of the intended string.

```
id: my_d7_node_news
label: 'Nodes (News)'
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
class: Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 7'
source:
  plugin: d7_node
  node_type: news
process:
  nid: tnid
  vid: vid
  title: title
  uid: node_uid
  status: status
  created: created
  changed: changed
  revision_uid: revision_uid
  revision_log: log
  revision_timestamp: timestamp
  'body/value':
    plugin: get
    source: 'body/value'
  'body/summary':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: some summary
  'body/format':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: rich_text
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: news
```

I tried multiple writing for the source: 'body/value' (e,g: source: body_value, etc, ...) with no luck...

Which syntax should I use to make successful mapping on body/value: body/value using the d7_node source plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  body:
    plugin: iterator
    source: body
    process:
      value: value
      format:
        plugin: default_value
        default_value: filtered_html
```

Comment: This has been renamed to the sub_process plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Just use 'body', as in:

```
body: body
```

That is what core d7_node migration does.